# Lyx add page number in abstract

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, abstract

Hi I'm desperately looking for a way to display the page number on my page in abstract. I'm trying to do this with the `\chead{\thepage}`, yet it won't work. The following screenshots show the view in lyx and the pdf output. As you see I tried the mentioned command at several positions without success. Awkwardly, previous pages and pages after the abstract are displaying the page numbers. I also have not rewritten the \abstract command in my preface.

It would be great if you could tell me how to add the page number on this page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't have enough information. Please add a Minimal Working Example, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4490/44524

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got the solution by myself. The problem was, that Lyx sets \thispagestyle{empty} per default for the abstract. To overcome this I had to set the page style as 'plain' after the minipage.

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\cfoot{\thepage}
```